# UTF8 not (fully) working in tables

Tags: tables, luatex, utf8

Is there a reason for UTF8 not working in table/tabular the way they do in normal text? I try to write a lower case sigma in a table. In the normal text, I can just put a σ and it's displayed correctly. But in a table writing σ it just doesn't show anything put a space. Instead, I have to use \sigma. I'm compiling with LuaLaTeX so UTF8 support shouldn't be a problem. Also, e.g. a ± works without any tricks. So why don't all UTF8 symbols work in tables the way they work in text?

EDIT: minimal working sample

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{arial}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *bd,
    ItalicFont = *i,
    BoldItalicFont = *bi]

\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
σ
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        σ & \sigma \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: UTF8 also works in tables in general. Maybe the table in your document is set in math mode which selects another font? Please show a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228), because otherwise we can only try to look in our crystal balls  and guess what is going on.

Comment: Obviously it's not in math mode. But I've created a minimal working sample, it doesn't get more minimal than this. Compile this with LuaLaTeX (i tried both Overleaf and local texlive 2023. You'll only see the sigma right of the vertical line, not the one on the left.

Comment: Well, the font you use (per default) does not contain this letter. The log says `Missing character: There is no σ (U+03C3) in font [lmroman10-regular]:+tlig`.

Comment: Please make an example that has `σ` outside of the table, another `σ` inside the table, and doesn't have math (`\sigma` would cause an error in your example).  Post that here.  If you get an error, copy and paste the error message.

Comment: I've changed the MWE now using Arial as I do in my main document, as I have no clue what alternative I could use from packages. And no, \sigma doesn't cause any errors. The only line referring to it in logs is "LaTeX Font Info:    Redeclaring math symbol \Sigma on input line 11." But if it does for you, add the textgreek package and replace it with \textsigma.  Either way, you'll still get the "There is no σ (U+03C3) in font" error.  But only once, proving that for some reason Arial (or any other default font) isn't being used in the table, but in text.

Comment: I've voted to reopen the question. If you remove the `table` environment, the sigma reappears as in regular text. So there's something weird going on.

Comment: @RichardRosner In your example, you select `\sfdefault` as default font but only after `\begin{document}` and therefore the font is already set. So usual text uses `\rmdefault` (which is Arial in your case), but every code which tries to switch to the default font switches to `\sfdefault` (which is `Latin Modern Sans in your case). The `{table}` environment resets the font to the default font, so it switches to Latin Modern Sans which does not contain sigma.

Comment: Why you change familydefault to sfdefault while sfdefault is not from arial but is from latin modern which has no sigma?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to switch `\familydefault`, you should do it before `\begin{document}` or explicitly use `\normalfont` afterwards in order to actually use it, otherwise the currently loaded font is still the previous default.

Also `\setmainfont` sets the font as default serif font (since that's the main font under default settings).

If you want to use `Arial` as your sans serif font and use this sans serif font as default font, you can load

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{arial}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *bd,
    ItalicFont = *i,
    BoldItalicFont = *bi]

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\begin{document}
σ
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{c|c}
        σ & \sigma \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick.

Answer (score 5):

It's unrelated to the `tabular` the `table` environment is resetting to the document default latin modern sans serif, which has no Greek

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{arial}[
    Extension = .ttf,
    UprightFont = *,
    BoldFont = *bd,
    ItalicFont = *i,
    BoldItalicFont = *bi]
\showoutput
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
1σ
\begin{table}
2σ
\end{table}

\end{document}
```